Alternating series of squares of multinomial coefficients
Question:
If $(1 + x + x^2)^{20} = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \cdots + a_{40}x^{40}$
Then what is the value of $a_0^2 - a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots - a_{19}^2$?
Answer:
The answer given for the above question is $\frac{1}{2}a_{20}(1-a_{20})$.
How would one go about proving this?
It seemed to me that the cube roots of unity might help in evaluating the sum but so far I have not made a lot of progress in that direction.

Taking into account the symmetry of coefficients $a_k=a_{40-k}$, this question is identical to this one found using (once more) approach0 searching engine.

This is a long-winded comment, and represents only my personal (uneducated, unsophisticated) reaction to the question. 
This is not an answer.

The answer given for the above question is $\frac{1}{2}a_{20}(1-a_{20})$.
How would one go about proving this?

Being ignorant in this area, I could be mistaken about the following:
My instinct is that to attack a problem likes this requires a slow steady build-up of mathematical intuition + specific pertinent mathematical tools.  I would imagine that after either a single year long undergraduate college course in combinatorics, or (perhaps) two such year long courses (where the second course involves advanced combinatorics), then the problem solver would have a reasonable mastery of the theory.
After such a mastery is obtained, then the problem solver could conquer the problem with only a reasonable amount of effort.  That is, the problem solver would avoid the need to re-invent the wheel, and avoid trying to discover the preliminary results that would be otherwise be spoon fed to the math student during the college courses.
Without such a mastery, I regard the attempt to attack such a problem as a very bad idea.

It is natural then for an OP (i.e. original poster) of the question to pose the math problem without displaying any serious work in this area.  That is, for the untrained math student, I (personally) would regard it as ridiculous for the math student to even try.  You have to learn to crawl, before you can walk.

However, presenting the problem on MathSE represents a quandary.
MathSE gives priority to maintaining a high quality repository of questions+answers, rather than education.  So, MathSE sets quality standards as to which posted questions are allowed to receive an answer.
One of the required ingredients to a MathSE question is context.
To quote one MathSE moderator:

I don't think that "effort" or an "attempt" constitute very good context. Context should explain to an outsider why the question is interesting, what tools ought to be used to solve the problem, what level the question is aimed at, etc. "Effort" can often serve as a proxy for these kinds of things, but "effort" is not the be-all and end-all.

Beyond that, for guidance on what MathSE questions are regarded as high quality, I refer you to this article on MathSE protocol, which attempts to summarize the desirable aspects of a posted question.
The linked article itself contains a link to a more detailed discussion of the desirable aspects of a posted question.

So, in summary, I think that it is very plausible that the OP of this posted question has a quandary.  Depending on whether the OP has been provided the necessary tools (whatever they are), it may not be rational for the OP to attempt to conquer such a problem.
On the other hand, absent such an attempt, and absent a discussion within the posted question of the pertinent tools, and possible solving strategies, I don't see how the posted question can be improved sufficiently enough to be regarded as a high quality question at MathSE.
